# Unity - ограничение позиции камеры относительно её вида

Tags: c#, unity3d

Всем привет. Может быть я не совсем понятно задал вопрос, но всё же, может кто-нибудь ответит.

Пишу игру RTS. Вид сверху.

В общем в чём проблема.
Я написал скрипт для увеличения вида камеры (обзора). Камера: Ortographic.
Также в этот скрипт добавил строки для перемещения (скроллинга) камеры. Поставил ограничение с помощью Mathf.Clamp. Теперь какой баг:
Когда я не увеличиваю вид камеры (Zoom in), ограничения работают нормально, камера не выходит за пределы. Но когда я увеличиваю **orthographicSize**, камера не может дойти до конца сцены, и получается, будто ограничение увеличилось.

И как можно сделать так, чтобы ограничение вида камеры увеличилось относительно **orthographicSize**?

Игру сделал под андроид.
Вот код для скроллинга камеры:

```
var pos = Camera.main.transform.position;
pos.x = Mathf.Clamp (Camera.main.transform.position.x - Input.GetTouch (0).deltaPosition.x * 0.15f, 6.0f, 30.0f);
pos.z = Mathf.Clamp (Camera.main.transform.position.z - Input.GetTouch (0).deltaPosition.y * 0.15f, -300.0f, 15.0f);
Camera.main.transform.position = pos;
```

Наверное, нормально не смог объяснить, если что, простите.
Заранее благодарен!

Comment: Чем то ваша тема напоминает https://answers.unity.com/questions/433665/need-help-with-2d-orthographic-camera-zooming.html Не оно ли вам надо?